# Get index of partial match in a list

Tags: python, list

Hi assuming I have the following list:

```
words = ['maritus', 'et', 'quolibet', 'is', 'habitancium', 'dico', 'locum~locus', 'domus', 'totus', 'tempus', 'vitis', 'is', 'de', 'quolibet', 'ipse']
```

and the following word: locus

and I want to get the index of where it is found in words ie: 6
the following:

```
ind = words.index('locus')
```

will only work for whole words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `next()` on a generator that yields each word in the `words` list that `locus` is `in`. However, since you want the index, you should `enumerate` the `words` list and only yield the index, `i`.

```
next(i for i, w in enumerate(words) if 'locus' in w)
#6
```

To get the indexes of all the occurrences, we can use a `list-comprehension`:

```
[i for i, w in enumerate(words) if 'locus' in w]
```

Comment: I am getting an error -ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Gannina Are you sure? I will add the output from the interpreter to the answer to show it works.

Comment: @Gannina I did forget the `enumerate` when I first posted it, so you probably copied the code before the edit which I added it.

Comment: Yes actually it was before enumerate. I know it was not part of my initial question but what if there are 2 instances of locus in the list...can I get the index of both with this method?

Comment: @Gannina Yes, I will updated the answer. Please accept then though!